# Unable to add Android manifest Permissions

Tags: android, permissions, android-activity, manifest

I am working on an android library project for weeks and having no problem so far.
But now i implemented a bit code to check to network status as following:

```
public Boolean getCurrentNetworkStatus(Activity activity) {
    ConnectivityManager cm;
    NetworkInfo netInfo = null;

    try {
         cm = (ConnectivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);          
         netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("MOCK", e);
    } 

    if(netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
        return True;
    } 

    return False;
}
```

My log.d gives the error that i am missing the ACCES_NETWORK_STATE permission. Here is where the trouble starts..

When opening my Manifest.xml i am not able to add an permission (already have 3 others). When i click add it gives an empty window saying: Create a new element at the top level, in temporary descriptors due to missing descriptors.

Trying to just add the permission to the manifest doesnt work ether. The code aint complaining but just says i am still missing the permission.

Besides this the Manifest.xml started giving me the warning: Should explicitly set android:icon, there is no default. But working on a library project i do not need an icon. (and never needed one too).

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="nl.test.projectInternet"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<application
    android:label="projectInternet"
    android:allowBackup="false">
    <activity android:name=".projectInternet"
              android:label="projectInternet">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application> </manifest>
```

The exact exception received is: Neither user 10021 not current process has android.permission.ACCES_NETWORK_STATE.

Anyone knows what i did wrong / should do to fix this?

Remember: The code is working properly on a other android project. Now i am working on a library and i am not able to add the permission! Simply adding it to the .xml wont work.

Comment: Can you please post content of your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Add this permission and clean the project <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: Already said: Trying to just add the permission to the manifest doesnt work ether. The code aint complaining but just says i am still missing the permission.

Comment: Are you missing the closing </manifest> tag or is it just a copy error? Some typo error in manifest can lead to strange behavior too.

Comment: Yup a copie, paste error from code to stackoverflow

Comment: Solution found! (sort of): It is still impossible to add permission with the add permission button. But the problem was that i am testing my library with unity. In order to test it i have to copie my new .jar file and ALSO my new manifest..

Answer (score 0):

You can follow me. step by step : such as

first add permission in AndroidMenifest.xml file.

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

second add CheckInternet Class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class CheckInternet 
{
    public static boolean checkConn(Context ctx)
    {
        ConnectivityManager conMgr =  (ConnectivityManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info == null)
            return false;
          if (!info.isConnected())
            return false;
          if (!info.isAvailable())
            return false;
          return true;


    }


}
```

and finally check internet from your activity. such as

```
    if (CheckInternet.checkConn(getBaseContext())) {
                // internet connect ok
            } else {
// internet connection not ok
}
```

Comment: I am unable to call with getBaseContext(). It doesnt exist.

Comment: your skype id give me, omor4android my skype id

Comment: suppose check internet permission from MainActivity.Class then you will be use MainActivity.this instead of getBaseContext() . ok

Answer (score 0):

Add this Permission in your manifest next to Access_corse_location.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Replace Your Method with following Method to Check Connection:

```
/**
 * Checking internet state
 * @param context
 * @return true if internet is enabled
 * else 
 * false
 */
public static boolean checkNetConnection(Context context){

    ConnectivityManager miManager=(ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo miInfo=miManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(miInfo!=null && miInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
        return true;
    }
    else if(miInfo!=null && miInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
        return true;
    }
    else if(miInfo!=null &&  miInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()){

        return true;
    }else{

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then Clean and Build your Project then Run it. It wont throw any error.

Comment: All you need is Just Context of your Activity or Service Class. Just Call this Method using following                                                             if(   checkNetConnection(this) ) { // Having Net Connection} else // No Connection.

Answer (score 0):

```
       import android.content.Context;
       import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
       import android.net.NetworkInfo;

       public class InternetConnection {

       private Context _context;

       public InternetConnection(Context context){
       this._context = context;
     }

       public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
       ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)  
       _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      if (connectivity != null)
      {
          NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
          if (info != null)
              for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                  if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                  {
                      return true;
                  }

      }
      return false;
      }
      }
```

In the Manifest

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <uses-permission 
      android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Try this.

Comment: Getting a nullpointerexception. But remember the code is not the problem. The fact that the manifest wont allow to add a permission is..

Answer (score 0):

If you run on OS > 6.0 try this:

from Activity call
verifyInetPermissions(this);

```
private static final int REQUEST_INET = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_INET = {
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
        Manifest.permission.INTERNET
};

public static void verifyInetPermissions(Activity activity) {
    // Check if we have Inet permission
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE);
    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, PERMISSIONS_INET, REQUEST_INET );
    }
}
```

Also I see that you missed one letter S, not ACCES_NETWORK_STATE, but ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.